# Unable to load DLL 'NImages': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: dll

I am getting this error when i am trying to use any DLL from Neurotechnology Verilook SDK

**{"Unable to load DLL 'NImages': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple "file not found" error, the most common mishap when you work with files.  Beware that it might also be *another* DLL that it cannot find, one that the DLL you're trying to load requires.  You can use SysInternals' ProcMon tool to diagnose this, you'll see it searching for the file.  Contact the vendor for support if that doesn't help.