# My Visual Studio 2017 VB.NET project is not finding a DLL! Is there an easy fix?

Tags: vb.net, dll

I am trying to make a custom, sandboxed program launcher and to do this I need to use the DLL `Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64` and, originally, this was not on my PC so I installed it with NuGet.
However, even once I had done this and copied it to every suitable directory I could think of, my program would still not compile with error:

> BC37225
> Failure writing debug information: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Even though I looked through so many questions and answers on this website, none of them have helped me. Here is my code:

```vb
Dim Process1 As Object

<DllImport("user32.dll")> Public Shared Function SetParent(ByVal hwndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hwndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button1.Text = My.Settings.App1Name
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Process1.StartInfo.FileName = (My.Settings.App1Link)
    Process1.Start()

    Do Until Process1.WaitForInputIdle = True
        'Nothing
    Loop
    'SetParent(Process1.MainWindowHandle, Panel1.Handle)
End Sub
```

I tried to download the DLL to the project directory and to the System32 directory but it would still not compile.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459307/unable-to-load-dll-nimages-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-exceptio

Comment: Hans Passent, that method did not work but I after borrowing a friend's computer to try to compile on, it worked so I assume my Windows installation might be missing the DLL itself